# Python Negative Number modulo positive number

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, modulo

How come `-20 % 3 = 1`?

Just confused with the formulae used for negative number % positive number.

(I have seen many question related in quora but still not clear with formula used)

Comment: Well, seems like `3-(20%3)`. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2341177

Comment: python does floor division , you can find a good explanation here http://python-history.blogspot.in/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: Note, this is very useful, and a bit more natural. Suppose you number your days 0-6, and you know you are on day 4, then what day was it 20 days ago? `(4 - 20) % 7 ==  -16 % 7 == 5`

Comment: @Kallz Difficult to understand

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How come days are calculated

Comment: Python follows the rules of mathematics, where modulo is either zero or has the same sign as the divisor. Effectively the division is truncated towards negative infinity. Languages like APL which dates back to the 1960's also implements modulo this way. C, C++, and some other languages have the remainder equal to zero or the same sign as the dividend, where effectively the division is rounded towards zero. The math / Python method has the advantage that the relationship (a + b m)%m = a, regardless if b is less than, equal to, or greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the formula but you can add x to the negative number such that `(x+ negative number)>=0` and `x` is a multiple of mod value . This is right because 
`x % k = (x+ y*k) % k`

Comment: Can you please explain with above numbers(-20%3 = 1).Cannot understand.

Comment: @havin - when truncating division towards negative infinity, `-20 / 3 = -7`, so `-20 % 3 = (-20) - (-21) = 1` or `3 x (-7) + 1 = -21 + 1 = -20` .

Comment: add 21 with -20  
`-20 % 3 = (-20 + 21) % 3  = 1 % 3 = 1`  
Here `(-20 + 21) % 3` can be written as `(-20 %3 ) + (21 % 3 )` .
Since `(21 % 3) = 0` , so it will not affect the answer nut will help us find the answer